# How to securely pass credentials in python?

Tags: python, security, password-encryption

Passing login credentials into a python script for a website. However, I want the credentials to not be stored as plaintext in the .py files. How can I securely store the login credentials in a .py file so it can use them to login?

Comment: You can store them in an encrypted file, and use a decryption library. But then you'll have to store the decryption key in the script, which is no better.

Comment: Why do the creds need to be stored in a .py file?  You could store them in another file (that's not checked into your version control), or in environment variables, or in a secret-management system that you query at run-time.  Using a secret-management system is generally preferred, though then you need some way to authenticate to *it*.

Comment: You could store the password in a separate file that is not in source control and is only available on the machine that needs it. Make its permissions the minimum  possible (hidden and read by user only). Now only the user can see it. Put it in an encrypted file system or whatever key store your system has, so that it can't be used by someone physically stealing the hard drive. And use an account with a narrow focus to reduce the chance you'll get malware from other activities. Be careful who as admin rights on the machine.

Comment: @user3553031 to clarify, it doesn't need to be stored in the py file just securely used by the py file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an environmental file in your project root directory and load in the variables from this file during runtime, in Python you can do this with the `python-dotenv` package.

```bash
$ pip install python-dotenv
```

**`credentials.py` File:**

```py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
load_dotenv(find_dotenv()) # Load the .env file.

# Fetch variables from the .env file.
account_username = os.getenv("ACCOUNT_USERNAME")
account_password = os.getenv("ACCOUNT_PASSWORD")
```

**`.env` File:**

```
ACCOUNT_USERNAME = SomeUser
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD = somestrongpassword123
```

And from there, you can use the `account_username` and `account_password` as normal to authenticate and login to the website.

---

**Security notice:** Be sure to add the `.env` file to your `.gitignore` so you avoid pushing your environmental file to version control.

Comment: so bottom line, it must be plaintext somewhere? (Unlike hashing which stores a hash but wont work in this case because the form checks a regular trimmed string password not a hash and you cant unhash a hash to get the string pass besides cracking like rainbow tables obv)

Comment: If you are worried about someone seeing the credentials in plain text in your project, then storing them hashed is equally going to be redundant since they'll be able to also see how you are unhashing them in your project to use them to login. Generally an environmental file is only stored on your local computer during development and in the production environment.